# page load onclick button

Tags: php, api, aweber

I tried many stuff like window.stop but wont work and tried to make some function in this code but fail todo again.

Here is my button

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me">

<?php

require_once('aweber_api/aweber_api.php');

// <!-- // Replace with the keys of your application
// // NEVER SHARE OR DISTRIBUTE YOUR APPLICATIONS'S KEYS! -->


$consumerKey    = "aaaa";
$consumerSecret = "bbbbb";

$aweber = new AWeberAPI($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);

if (empty($_COOKIE['accessToken'])) 
{
    if (empty($_GET['oauth_token'])) {
        $callbackUrl = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        list($requestToken, $requestTokenSecret) = $aweber->getRequestToken($callbackUrl);
        setcookie('requestTokenSecret', $requestTokenSecret);
        setcookie('callbackUrl', $callbackUrl);
        header("Location: {$aweber->getAuthorizeUrl()}");
        exit();
    }

    $aweber->user->tokenSecret = $_COOKIE['requestTokenSecret'];
    $aweber->user->requestToken = $_GET['oauth_token'];
    $aweber->user->verifier = $_GET['oauth_verifier'];
    list($accessToken, $accessTokenSecret) = $aweber->getAccessToken();
    setcookie('accessToken', $accessToken);
    setcookie('accessTokenSecret', $accessTokenSecret);
    header('Location: '.$_COOKIE['callbackUrl']);
    exit();
}

# set this to true to view the actual api request and response
$aweber->adapter->debug = false;

$account = $aweber->getAccount($_COOKIE['accessToken'], $_COOKIE['accessTokenSecret']);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>AWeber Test Application</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
<body>
<?php
foreach($account->lists as $offset => $list) {
?>
<h1>List: <?php echo $list->name; ?></h1>
<h3><?php echo $list->id; ?></h3>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="stat">Subject</th>
    <th class="value">Sent</th>
    <th class="value">Stats</th>
  </tr>
<?php
foreach($list->campaigns as $campaign) {
    if ($campaign->type == 'broadcast_campaign') {
?>
    <tr>
        <td class="stat"><em><?php echo $campaign->subject; ?></em></td>
        <td class="value"><?php echo date('F j, Y h:iA', strtotime($campaign->sent_at)); ?></td>
        <td class="value"><ul>
              <li><b>Opened:</b>  <?php echo $campaign->total_opens; ?></li>
              <li><b>Sent:</b>  <?php echo $campaign->total_sent; ?></li>
              <li><b>Clicked:</b>  <?php echo $campaign->total_clicks; ?></li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    <?php
    }
} ?>
</table>
<?php }
?>
<body>
</html>
```

This page taking me to redirect aweber login but I want one button, and on button click take me to login page of aweber and then after login redirect me to same page.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please update your question with exact issue. And where is your button?

Comment: @SmitRaval please do check i just added button. Problem is when I load this page it taking me to aweber login. But i want to go after clicking button. And after Login I want to come back at the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not checking if the button is clicked and when the page loads your script is running. Also you can check your request and only if it is POST do something. Based on your code:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="myButton" value="Click Me">
</form>

<?php
    // Check if the request is post
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        // Check if the button is clicked
        if (isset($_POST['myButton'])) {
            // Your code here
        }
    }

    // Some other code here
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried what you shared with me. my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mohsinshaikh/0c23u4p7/ button is not working . Thank you so much vaios

Comment: I've edited my answer. Better change the type of the input to submit instead of button and put it in a form element to specify that you want a POST request. Glad that I helped.

Comment: You are super hero. This is was trying from two days. :) Thanks again